# Why is my css not working with image smoothing

Tags: html, css, image

I've bean trying to make a background, but the image smoothing is not working:

```css
img {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
}

html {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

#webpage-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="res/images/POTATO_BACKGROUND.png" id="webpage-background" style="image-rendering: pixelated;">
  <canvas>
    </body>
```

and it always results in this:

[image: this is a section of the image]

Comment: What is your expectation with the code provided? The HTML is invalid as well without a closing `</canvas>` tag. Can you put your image somewhere that can be linked to, so we can view it?

Comment: What happens with different values of image smoothing? And is there more code we need to see? Where for example are you scaling the image or is it just shown with its natural dimensions?